# How can I replace “<” and “>” with “&lt;” and “&gt; except <img src=""> and <a href="">text</a> tags in Perl

Tags: html, perl, replace, tags

I want to replace `<` and `>` with `&lt;` and `&gt;` except `<img src="">` and `<a href="">text</a>` tags in Perl through using regex:

```
$a= qq~<a href="">test</a> <script> <img src="">~;
$a =~ s/<([^img|a])/&lt;$1/ig;
$a =~ s/([^<a(.*?)])>/$1&gt;/ig;
print "\n$a\n";
```

but it replace inner '>' also like

```
<a href=""&gt;test&lt;/a> &lt;script&gt; <img src=""&gt;
```

Comment: it would be interesting to know what problem you're trying to solve here, because I suspect that what you're trying to get an answer for may not be the best solution to the original problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this straightforward approach:

```
$a =~ s/</&lt;/g;
$a =~ s/>/&gt;/g;
# Fix "a" & "img"
$a =~ s/&lt;a\s(.*?)&gt;(.*?)&lt;\/a&gt;/<a $1>$2<\/a>/g;
$a =~ s/&lt;img\s(.*?)&gt;/<img $1>/g;
```

Note:

`[^img|a]` is `not i,m,g,a or |`

If you need to find `<` not followed by `img` or `a` - use negative lookahead:

```
/<(?!img|a)/
```

Comment: this fails if the input string already contains `&lt;` entities.